# Embed a webservice that converts address to latitude/longitude via iframe

Tags: r, iframe, latitude-longitude, bookdown

I write a `bookdown` in `R`. In this html project I can embed `iframe`. At one point I like to ask visitors to check their geo-coordinates (latitude/longitude) for any address. I like visitors to be able to do this inside my project/website. I there a way and a service that I can embed in my project? I don't plan to use an API.